# why does JSONDeserializer exclude xml tag from json input string

Tags: json-deserialization

I've below json string

```
{"metadata":"<xml><item><name>Memory</name><Fullname>NULL</Fullname></item></xml>"}
```

when I deserialize this using flexjson it is excluding all xml tags from above json and give this value "Memory NULL"

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just looking at it in a browser which hides the tags?

Comment: To check that the browser is not hiding the tags, print length of the string, or escape it properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: @Wrikken, oh! Thanks Yes browser hides the tags..